# How do I write a custom Capybara Selector with pure Ruby (No XPath/CSS)

Tags: capybara

In the acceptance tests for my application, I need to match table cells based on column headers, taking into account the `colspan` attributes on both the headers and table cells. I want to write a custom matcher to do this, but it seems to me that XPath isn't cut out for the job. (Sure, maybe it's possible to do something like this in XPath, but it doesn't seem to me like such a monster XPath expression would be very easy to write, read, or maintain.)

So what I'd like to do is write a custom Capybara selector which doesn't rely on the `xpath` or `css` DSL methods defined in `Capybara::Selector`. Instead, I'd like to use pure Ruby code for this, as I believe Ruby is much better suited for this problem than XPath is. How would I go about doing this? (E.g. Could I create my own selector object and append it to `Capybara::Selector.all`, or something?)

*(Cross-posted from the [Capybara mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/nEkiw7GnCqE))*

---

**TL;DR:**

How do I define my own Capybara matcher without being limited to the use of XPath or CSS? XPath is fine in most cases, but right now I need something with a bit more power.

Comment: Please give an example of method signature.

Comment: @AndreyBotalov What method signature? The signature of Capybara's finder methods? I'd expect to be able to use it like any other Capybara selector: `page.all(:table_cell, "Column Header")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible. Capybara supports only those locator types that are supported by underlying driver.

[Selenium Webdriver supports XPath, CSS, class name, id, name, link text, partial link text, tag name locator types](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#POST_/session/%3asessionId/element). Other drivers have a lower number of choices.

[As you](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb#L149) [see](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/query.rb#L97) in Capybara code selector's block should return a single XPath or CSS expression.

CSS locators don't allow to locate elements by text. So you should use XPath. You can do something like this to locate table cells by column name:

```
Capybara.add_selector(:table_cell) do
  xpath { |column_name| "//td[1 + count(//th[.='#{column_name}']/preceding-sibling::th)]" }
end
page.all(:table_cell, 'Column Header')
```

Also you can write XPathes in Ruby using [xpath gem](https://github.com/jnicklas/xpath).

But xpath gem doesn't currently support all [XPath functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Functions_and_operators). For example it doesn't support `count()` function used in snippet above. You can add support for it there yourself.

Also Ruby code that you will write using xpath gem will be larger than needed XPath expression string.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately an XPath solution for my problem would be much more complicated than that. As I said in the original question, I need one that takes `colspan` into account.

I think you're right about what I want not being possible though. I looked at the source for Capybara a bit, and it seemed to me that the drivers themselves are what require the use of XPath.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this in the future, my final solution was to just write a plain old Ruby class for parsing and processing HTML tables via Capybara's API. Unfortunately such a solution doesn't take advantage of the synchronization features of Capybara and doesn't blend in with Capybara's existing APIs, but it works well enough for me.